# Is there a way to make a template match all pointer types?

Tags: c++, templates, lua

Is there a way to make a templated C++ function implicitly convert all pointers to a `void*`? I'm working on a lightweight Lua binding and I'd like to avoid writing the exact same function for every pointer type when the `void*` version is all I need.

Declaration:

```
template<class T>
T GetFromStack(lua_State* L, int index);
```

Definition:

```
template<> void* GetFromStack<void*>(lua_State* L, int index)
{
    return lua_touserdata(L, index);
}
```

If I was to call `myVariable = GetFromStack<MyStruct*>(L, 0);`, the C++ compiler would complain that I haven't defined a function for a `MyStruct*`. Is it possible to have *every* pointer type matched to the `void*` version implicitly?

EDIT:

I see how my question is a bit confusing, I'm not really sure how to word it. I'm attempting to come up with an automatic binding system. This `GetFromStack` function is called from another templated function:

```
template<class T_return, class T_param1, class T_param2 >
int LuaFunction(lua_State* L, T_return (*func)(T_param1,T_param2));
```

which is implemented like this:

```
template<class T_return, class T_param1, class T_param2 >
int LuaFunction(lua_State* L, T_return (*func)(T_param1,T_param2))
{
    T_param1 a = GetFromStack<T_param1>(L, 1);
    T_param2 b = GetFromStack<T_param2>(L, 2);
    T_return ret = func(a,b); 
    PushLuaType(L, ret); // <-- This is another templated function 
                         // like GetFromStack that has the same problem
    return 1;
}
```

I then create a Lua version of whatever function I want to expose to Lua with a simple macro:

```
#define DeclareLuaFunction(function) \
    static int ##function##_lua_(lua_State* L) \
    { \
        return LuaFunction(L, function); \
    }
```

This works really well so long as I use the predefined types. I have versions of `GetFromStack` written for all the "basic" types (int, float, etc) and obviously `void*`. But I don't want to have to write one for every one of my custom type's pointers. When I create a function that uses a `MyStruct2`, I'd have to write yet another version of `GetFromStack` that's identical to every other `pointer` version.

This system would be used like this:

```
struct MyStruct
{
    int a;
    float b;
};

int AddToMyStruct(MyStruct* s, int x)
{
    int original = s->a;
    s->a += x;
    return original;
}

DeclareLuaFunction(AddToMyStruct);
```

Which would then have `T_return` as an `int`, `T_param1` as a `MyStruct*` and `T_param2` as an integer too. I already have `int` versions of `GetFromStack` and `PushLuaType`, but I don't have `MyStruct*` versions. With the way it's implemented now, I'd have to write a new version of `GetFromStack` for every type I come up with, even though every implementation would be the same.

EDIT: Andreas' solution would work if theres a way I can determine if a type is a pointer or not at compile type. If my T_param1 is a `MyStruct*`, it will be passed as such to `GetFromStack`, instead of as a `MyStruct`.

Comment: So you want `GetFromStack<MyStruct*>(L, 0)` to return a `void*`, not a `MyStruct*`? I don't see how that can possibly be useful. When I read something like `GetFromStack<MyStruct*>(L, 0)`, I expect the thing to return a `MyStruct*`, not a `void*`, so that I can actually do something with it. You use `void*` when you have no idea what the type is, but it appears in this case you already know what it is in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking... what's wrong with just `void* GetFromStack(lua_State* L, int index)`? (i.e. not using the template)

Comment: You seem to be a bit confused. The specification of lua_touserdata() is exactly what you ask for! `void *lua_touserdata (lua_State *L, int index);`. Just use it as it stands if `void *` are all you need.

Comment: @CAFxX: Very valid point based on my original question. I've clarified a bit to explain exactly why I need a templated solution.

Comment: @Kyle: So is there any difference in what `GetFromStack()` does, depending on whether it should return a pointer type or not? If there isn't maybe a `template <class T> T GetFromStack(...)` is all you need and just skip the `void *` overload as it will confuse the compiler (as all ptrs are implicitly convertible to `void *`)

Comment: @Andreas: Yes, there is. If the type is built in (`int`, `float`, `const char*`, etc), I would call `lua_tointeger`, `lua_tonumber`, etc. I only want to use `lua_touserdata` if they type is a user-defined type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, here's a new try based on your additional info. As has been said before, much of this could be done much easier if you opt to use C++11, but this should work in most older compilers as well.

First you need a way to detect whether your template param T is a pointer, you could either use `std::is_pointer<>` (which is preferable) or define one yourself like:

```
template <class T>
struct is_pointer
{
  enum {value = false};
};

template <class T>
struct is_pointer<T *>
{
  enum {value = true};
};

template <class T>
struct is_pointer<const T *>
{
  enum {value = true};
};
```

Next you need to alter your implementation based on it. To do that we introduce a helper class (or struct as I'm too lazy to write `public`) which has several specializations, one for each ordinary type and one for pointers:

```
template <bool ispointer, class T>
struct GetFromStackHelper;

template <>
struct GetFromStackHelper<false, int>
{
  static int GetFromStackFun(lua_State *l, int index)
  {
    return lua_tointeger(l, index);
  }
};

// ... add the rest of the built in types here

template <class T>
struct GetFromStackHelper<true, T>
{
  static T GetFromStackFun(lua_State *l, int index)
  {
    return static_cast<T>(lua_touserdata(l, index));
  }
};
```

Finally we tie it together with the `GetFromStack` function, which now should not have any specializations:

```
template <class T>
T GetFromStack(lua_State *l, int index)
{
  return GetFromStackHelper<is_pointer<T>::value, T>::GetFromStackFun(l, index);
}
```

Which you could use as:

```
int i = GetFromStack<int>(luaState, 6);
MyStruct *p = GetFromStack<MyStruct *>(luaState, 5);
```

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for, however I don't think it will work with my templated function that calls `GetFromStack`. I've clarified my original question with some more information.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand it correctly, you need to implement the function differently for different types, but the implementation happens to be the same for all pointer types.

If the value was passed as a parameter, you'd use normal function overloading. In this case, you can use `enable_if`.

```
template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_pointer<T>::value, T>::type
    GetFromStack(lua_State* L, int index)
{
    return lua_touserdata(L, index);
}
```

Comment: I'm fairly certain `std::enable_if` isn't part of C++03. Neither is `std::is_pointer`.

Comment: @avakar: I would prefer a standards-conforming implemention if at all possible. C++98 would be ideal. I've updated my original question with more information.

Comment: @Kyle: `enable_if<>` is available in the boost library, [example](https://gist.github.com/bd7c7d7da73aac8183ea)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: Unfortunately this project isn't using boost.

Comment: @Kyle, even in C++98, both `enable_if` and `is_pointer` are few lines of code. Take a look at Boost implementation and just copy it over.

Comment: @avakar: That was my point. He didn't ask for C++11, so handing him a C++11 solution was useless to him. If he wanted C++11, he'd have either asked for it or put it in his tags. You can't assume that everyone's on the latest-and-greatest thing.

Comment: @NicolBolas, he didn't ask for C++03 either. And again, you don't need C++11 to get the equivalent functionality.

Comment: @Nicol: Many, if not most, major compilers offer support for these libraries in their current versions. It is not unreasonable to assume such support- especially when there is C++03 equivalence in Boost.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure if this is what you're looking for, but...

How about passing function pointers?

Your compiler's probably going to give you a bunch of warnings, but it should work.

```
void *GetFromStack(void *p, int index, void * (*func)(void *, int)) {
    return func(p, index);
}
```

`void * (*func)(void *, int)` is a function pointer to one that takes a void pointer and an int and returns a void pointer, which you supply as the first 2 parameters to GetFromStack. Just use the reference operator `&` to get a function pointer for the function you want it to call.